# Add text to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

(updated)
I have ggplot like this, but then the x axis Date scaled:

```
g1 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar()
```

Above two bars (lets say `VS2` and `IF`, but in my graph it is a date) I want to put a text label above the bars at height 13.000.

I tried a lot of things, but this is what came closest:
This is what I tried in my graph with the Date axis
`g1 + geom_text(aes(as.Date("2014-10-05"), 13000), label="boat")`

but this adds only one to the graph and as soon as I try to extend it, for example with

```
g1 + geom_text(aes(c(as.Date("2014-10-05"),as.Date("2014-10-20")) , 13000), label=c("boat", "train"))
```

then I get the error:

> Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the
>   dataProblems:c(as.Date("2014-10-05"), as.Date("2014-10-20"))

I also tried to read the text and labels from a dataframe (`oefen`), where I used the same names as the original plot

```
g1 + geom_text(data=oefen, aes(x=newdat, y=Number, label=oefen$labs, fill=1))
```

I get the error

> Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

I tried many other solutions, but cannot find the answer. What am I missing?

Comment: Difficult to follow without a reproducible example. However, what about `df <- data.frame(x = as.Date(c("2014-10-04", "2014-10-08", "2014-11-06") ), y = sample(1:3, 3), label = sample(letters, 3)); ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = label)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + geom_text(y = 4) + ylim(c(0, 4))`?

Comment: Hi lukeA, thanks for your answer. Your solution comes close, but what I want is only those letters (so no bars), plotted on my original g1 stacked bargraph. I have a barplot like this: ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar(), but the xaxis is a Date variable. Above only two bars I want to plot a letter. Is that clearer?

Comment: @Rosanne please post a simple reproducible code example using diamonds dataset.

Comment: @smci I gave it an update, is it clearer like this?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Consider using `annotate()` to place whatever text where you want at a given location on the plot.  Factor variables, as in the clarity factor on the x-axis, have a number for each level, so you can use that number to locate the text.  I assume date variables have the same usage.:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar() +
  annotate("text", x=8, y=13000, label= "boat") + 
  annotate("text", x = 4, y=13000, label = "ship")
```

[image]

**EDIT after COMMENT**

For efficiency, you can combine the annotations, such as this:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar() +
  annotate("text", x = c(2,4,6,8), y=13000, label = c("two", "ship", "six", "boat"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for. I tried to use annotate before, but it didn't work then, maybe it was all too messed up. I was just wondering as I want to add 6 labels if there is a way to combine it all in one piece of script instead of using annotate six times? Anyhow, Ill just put it down 6 times now as it finally works. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I added a suggested technique for multiple annotations in one line.  If this answers your question, please consider accepting it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Using following:
To use text after a digit or points [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX6bz.png)

After Using in `geom_text(paste0(percent, "%"))` it looked like this
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC9hS.png)