# scatter plot with single regression line instead of multiple regression lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to get single regression line and correlation coefficient instead of multiple regression lines. My code is shown below.

```
d1 <- structure(list(x1 = c(50.42,62.59,42.53,55.38,65.23,66.17,47.20,29.40,46.22,65.91), y1 = c(7.00,7.50,4.50,7.58,4.00,4.67,3.50,3.00,3.50,4.63)), .Names = c("x1", "y1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))
d2 <- structure(list(x2 = c(33.65,39.16,46.93,35.75,34.50,31.16,44.72,28.63,42.73,40.54,32.14,33.56), y2 = c(3.00,4.00,3.80,2.76,3.54,3.13,3.50,2.92,4.18,4.22,3.23,2.56)), .Names = c("x2", "y2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
names(d2) <- c("x1", "y2")
df <- rbind(melt(d1, id.vars = "x1"), melt(d2, id.vars = "x1"))
p1 <-ggplot(df, aes(x1, y = value, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_point(size=4) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),
        axis.title=element_text(size=18,face="bold"), plot.title=element_text(size=32,face="bold"),
        legend.text=element_text(size=16), 
        legend.justification=c(0,1),legend.position=c(0,1),legend.title=element_blank()

        ) + theme(legend.background = element_rect(
                                  size=0.5, linetype="solid", 
                                  colour ="black"), panel.border = element_rect(color="black", size=1, linetype="solid")) + theme(aspect.ratio=1) +
  labs(x = "x axis", y = "y axis") + 
 xlim(0,100) + 
 ylim(0,10) +  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, linetype="solid", fullrange=TRUE) +  ggtitle("My first plot") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("green","red"), labels = c("d1", "d2"))
```

Are there any easy way for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `geom_smooth` add `color="black"` (or whatever color you want) outside of `aes`. This will override the color aesthetic specified in the call to `ggplot` and result in a single regression line.

```
geom_smooth(color="black", method="lm", se=FALSE, linetype="solid", fullrange=TRUE) +
```

Regarding your comment about annotation: `d1` and `d2` don't exist in the `df` data frame. Try this:

```
annotate(x=20, y=5, label=paste("R = ", round(cor(df$x1, df$value),2)), geom="text", size=4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are there any way to print correlation coefficient on the plot. I tried like this : annotate(x=25, y=5, label=paste("R = ", round(cor(df$d1, df$d2),2)), geom="text", size=10.5)  . But it doesn't work.

Comment: You could just use text(x, ...) to add text to a plot.

Comment: `text` works with base graphics, but `ggplot` requires either `ggplot` functions or `grid` functions.

Comment: @eipi10  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're right. This older post explains how to add text to ggplot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755576/add-text-to-ggplot