# How to get the summarized statistics for a grouped Boxplot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have plotted a grouped Boxplot using ggplot with the code below:

```
ggplot(Data, `aes(x=Date$Result,y=Data$delta,fill=Data$ID))+geom_boxplot()+xlab("asdf")+ylab("fdsa")+guides(fill=guide_legend(title = "Results"))`
```

I would like to have a summarized (grouped) statistics containing mean, median, sd etc. as text displayed below the boxplot, how should I do that?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need but I have used this for my graphs: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-beautiful-plots-in-r-with-summary-statistics-labels/

Comment: it is exactly what I want but I don't have rstatix and ggpubr installed right now on my computer it is also not possible to install them for now....:(

Comment: Are you able to share a MRE? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @Skaqqs thanks for your reply. Because the task was urgent, I had to find some other solutions: I directly did a summary of this dataset with mean and median and so on. I think my problem can be solved easily with some packages, but I work in a closed environment for security reason...

Comment: For posterity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014187/displaying-text-below-the-plot-generated-by-ggplot2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755576/add-text-to-ggplot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553077/adding-summary-statistics-to-a-graph-using-the-annotation-feature-ggplot2